# Illegal string offset (PHP Warning)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter Framework.Actually, I'm trying to display an **array** in the **view**.But it shows some error.I've checked my code but still unable to find the mistake. Any help will be highly appreciated.

**models/users_model.php**

```
class Users_model extends CI_Model{

            public function getUsers(){
                return array(
                        'first' => 'Farhan Khan',
                        'second' => 'Abdul Wali',
                        'third' => 'Shahzaib Kamal'
                        );
            }

        }
```

**controller/users.php**

```
 class Users extends CI_Controller{

        public function index(){
            $this->load->model('Users_model');
            $data['users'] = $this->Users_model->getUsers();

            $this->load->view('users_list', $data);
        }

    }
```

**views/users_list.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Users List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            echo $user['first'];
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**The error i get is:**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Illegal string offset 'first'

Comment: Did you try any of the answers don't forget to accept one that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Users List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            echo $user."<br/>";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

OR

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Users List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            foreach ($users as $key=>$value) {
                 echo $key."=>".$value."<br/>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only a single one dimensional  `array` returned by the model. So when you do the `foreach` loop you are actually iterating through that and you get the elements of that array.

You can confirm it by modifying the view.

```
<?php
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            echo $user."<br/>";
        }

     //or you can simply do a var_dump($users);
    ?>
```

If you want to fix it then you need to return a multi dimensional array. I am assuming that you want to return more than one user in the future.

```
public function getUsers(){
                $users = [];
                $users[] =  array(
                        'first' => 'Farhan Khan',
                        'second' => 'Abdul Wali',
                        'third' => 'Shahzaib Kamal'
                        );
                return $users;
            }
```

Comment: Great, Can you please tell me what are the doubts you have?

Comment: Actually, i couldn't understand why you used   "$users[] =  array(..." instead of   "return array(..."

Comment: I assume you want to return multiple users but you are rather returning only one `user`. If you want to return multiple users what you need a 2D array. That is a array if users. That's the why I first created a `users` array and then added users to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way

> Remember with CodeIgniter **first letter of class and filename only upper case** as explained [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

Model: **User_model.php** filename

```
public function getUsers() {
   return $this->db->get('users')->result_array();
}
```

Controller **Users.php** filename

```
public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user_model'); // User_model.php
}

public function index() {
    $data['users'] = $this->user_model->getUsers();
    $this->load->view('users', $data);
}
```

View

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
   echo $user['first']; // first will be a column name.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing a little bit mistake --

your array --

```
$arr = array(
    'first' => 'Farhan Khan',
    'second' => 'Abdul Wali',
    'third' => 'Shahzaib Kamal'
    );
```

when you will print this array using that --

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

then output will be like that --

```
Array
(
    [first] => Farhan Khan
    [second] => Abdul Wali
    [third] => Shahzaib Kamal
)
```

and inside foreach its print array with indexing like 0,1,2,3... but here is not any index inside array that`s why giving this error..